# How to bundle JOGL with NetBeans Platform?

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, jogl

I was going to use both JOGL and NetBeans platform. I have trouble embedding JOGL native libs. Maybe there is a simple way to reuse `.nbm`s from NetBeans OpenGL Plugin? Or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing NBMs from [NetBeans OpenGL Pack](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3260/netbeans-opengl-pack) should work at least for NetBeans 7.1. Have a look at this post: http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-getting-started-jogl.

If you are using Maven, a quick solution is to create a wrapper module for JOGL and Gluegen with the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It is essential to add the following public package definitions to the `nbm-maven-plugin` configuration:

```
<publicPackages>
    <publicPackage>com.jogamp.*</publicPackage>
    <publicPackage>javax.media.*</publicPackage>
    <publicPackage>jogamp.*</publicPackage>
</publicPackages>
```

I suppose a wrapper module can be created from NetBeans IDE, though I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing specifically what your problem is, here's a way to just generally get JOGL running in Netbeans:

1. Download a JOGL release that suits your platform. As of march 2011, grab one from http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/archive/, you'll want one file named "jogl-2.0-(build)-(date)-(platform).7z"
2. Unzip it somewhere on your disk. I usually create a /sdk or c:\sdk and drop stuff there but that's up to you.
3. Add the jars to your project. In Netbeans, you can create a "library" (Tools > Libraries) and add the jars there. Oh, and make sure you actually add this library to your project, right-click the "libraries" for your project. Probably you will do just fine adding these jars from the JOGL distribution:

   - gluegen-rt.jar
   - jogl.all.jar
   - nativewindow.all.jar
   - newt.all.jar
4. In Eclipse you can add native files to a "library", but - afaik - you can't do this is Netbeans. You'll need to go in to the project properties and select "Run" on the left, and then add this Java VM option: "-Djava.library.path=/sdk/jogl/lib". Make sure to enter this as a VM option, not as arguments to the class. Also, of course replace /sdk/jogl with wherever you placed the files. And without the quotes, and no spaces anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for excellent write up, but I already knew how to do it. My main issue is how to create standalone application which is using JOGL. And this application should have minimal installation requirements, only JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use the JARs containing the native libraries as we do with Java Web Start.

Comment: Aren't some special mechanisms required to load those libraries? AFAIK WebStart does this automatically: unzip natives to temp and load them with System.load() (or similar). One way or the other the OpenGL plugin somewhat manages to pack natives and it seems it doesn't require any additional steps to work. Maybe it's using some NetBeans specific native extension hooks or sth...

Comment: You should ask that question on the JogAmp forum as the maintainer of the OpenGL pack comes there often, he could fix your problem.